# How to have a condition simulating an error after a rackPick in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with anylogic because I am not able to simulate an error happening to the moving resource (I have only one moving resource) of the rackPick block.

1. I tried to increase the delay (but I think this is not possible to do at runtime, because once the item has been picked from the rack store, I can find no way to restore the old delay)
2. I tried to reduce the speed of the moving resource (accessing to the correspondent resource pool), but I have the same problem described in point 1.

How can I do that?
I just need the moving resource to pause its job and resume programmatically.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky one, here is one possible way:

1. make your RackRick/Store use a ResourcePool with custom agents
2. make the ResourcePool use a Downtime block
3. Setup the downtime block to resemble your failures. Easiest if you have stochastic failure rates.

Alternatively, you can experiment with priorities: have a very high-prior task that can preempt your RackPick/Store task. Set the RackPick "Task preemption policy" to "Wait for original resource".

(Will need some trial'n'error on your end :) )

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved using a downtime block, starting a task to simulate an error happening and stopping it to simulate the error being solved.